# How can I create a 'generic' control in Asp.Net MVC Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, generics, razor

I'm trying to write a generic (meaning useful in many places) control that I can reuse throughout my company.

I'm having problems with actual C# generics in my view and viewmodel.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

Generic partial view: (`_Control.cshtml`)

```
@model SimpleExample<dynamic> 

@Model.HtmlTemplate(Model.Data)
```

ViewData: (`SimpleExample.cs`)

```
public class SimpleExample<T>
{
    public T Data;
    public Func<T, System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult> HtmlTemplate;
}
```

Example usage: (`FullView.cshtml`)

```
@model Foo.MyViewData

@Html.Partial("_Control", new SimpleExample<MyViewData>
{
    Data = Model,
    HtmlTemplate = @<div>@item.SomeProperty</div>
})
```

The important part of the functionality I'm looking for is that consumers get a typed object when writing their Html inline so they can use Intellisense (as in `FullView.cshtml`).

Everything compiles fine and the intellisense is working, but I'm getting the error an runtime:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
'AnytimeHealth.Web.ViewData.SimpleExample`1[Foo.MyViewData]', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 
'AnytimeHealth.Web.ViewData.SimpleExample`1[System.Object]'.
```

I've read that I might be able to use covarience on my generic type to get this to work, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Could you please instruct me how I can get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the define in `_Control.cshtml`:

`@model SimpleExample<dynamic>` to `@model dynamic`.

It will work, but will lose the intellisense of `SimpleExample`, the intellisense of `MyViewData` will still work.

I think it's because the dynamic type will be known in runtime, but the type of generics

require an early time(maybe is compile time), at that point, only `object` is be known.

Comment: This is working for me, except I lose intellisense in _Control `:(`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generic Object and then, using reflection, render the properties of this object (using an helper to list the properties). This is the same approach used by Twitter Bootstrap for MVC 4 (from wich part of this code has been copied, for convenience) : http://nuget.org/packages/twitter.bootstrap.mvc4

_Control.cshtml

```
@model Object
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>@Model.GetLabel()</legend>
        @foreach (var property in Model.VisibleProperties())
        {
            using(Html.ControlGroupFor(property.Name)){
                @Html.Label(property.Name)
                @Html.Editor(property.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessage(property.Name, null)
            }
        }
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Helper.cs

```
public static string GetLabel(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    var meta = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(null, propertyInfo.DeclaringType, propertyInfo.Name);
    return meta.GetDisplayName();
}

public static PropertyInfo[] VisibleProperties(this IEnumerable Model)
{
    var elementType = Model.GetType().GetElementType();
    if (elementType == null)
    {
        elementType = Model.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
    return elementType.GetProperties().Where(info => info.Name != elementType.IdentifierPropertyName()).ToArray();
}

public static PropertyInfo[] VisibleProperties(this Object model)
{
    return model.GetType().GetProperties().Where(info => info.Name != model.IdentifierPropertyName()).ToArray();
}
```